# Organizing files TO folders (Module programming)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, module

I am creating a visual c++ project now, and I would like to make some way to arrange files. I tried to create folders but it seems it is pretty hard to make them into visual studio, because these folders are empty and after including to the solution only I am going work on them (like Java packages. You first add them and code in it, in the same IDE, same project).

It seems like this way is not working because I can not add anything to the include files. So I tried to create filters. It is not a physical divide of files but if this is the way c++ community code then I have no problem. Otherwise could be a probvlem because this is my university project.

So in case the best is "filters", how can I call from one filter to another? Look at the below example

**FilterFolder1**

- people.h
- people.cpp

**FilterFolder2**

- vehicles.h
- vehicles.cpp

Now, I have a problem in arranging the stuff in this way as well. Bceuase even I right click on **FilterFolder1** and select *Add -> C++ Class* still  that class is created in it's default location, header file in **Header Files** filter and cpp file in **Source Files** filter. I had to manually drag and drop those files to make the above architecture.

Now, how can I call from people class (people.h and people.cpp) to vehicle class (vehicles.h and vehicles.cpp) because they are in two folders which I FORCED them to see like above?

What I did is correct or wrong? If correct, what is thhe answer for the above? If wrong, what is the correct way of organizing files and using it?

Comment: Have you tried this "Show All Files" clicky thingy in the Solution Explorer? If not, then try it. Then right-click on some area or item on the Solution Explorer to give you those handy tools that makes handling real folders/directories easy.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: Do I need to "include" them? Right click on folder in "view all files" -> Include in project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders and filters does not matter in your case. Simply call vehicle class from people class and go on. If you want to organize code *logically*, instead of *physically*, use [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually this is a Computer Vision Project. If it is still no matter (I mean, in Java, if we did not orgabize them to packages, it becomes "bad SE") then I am OK. Is this is the way it happens in C++ community? Please help

Comment: In C++ there is no relevance between placement of the file in folders and its contents. Java treats folders as namespaces, unlike C++. Just make sure, that every file is compiled.